# ValueError: Invalid field project.task.user_id in leaf

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

one of my colleagues encounters error when book in timesheet in Odoo. It happens after upgrading from 14 to 16.

Meanwhile, my account works fine.

Could you help?
Thanks

Version: 16.0+e-20230925

```
RPC_ERROR
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying
result = func()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1611, in _serve_ir_http
response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1815, in dispatch
result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
result = endpoint(**request.params)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 697, in route_wrapper
result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
File "/mnt/other_addons/ks_list_view_manager/controllers/lvm_controller.py", line 17, in call_kw
call_kw_result = super(LvmController, self).call_kw(
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 697, in route_wrapper
result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 42, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 457, in call_kw
result = _call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 430, in _call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/mnt/custom_addons/odoo_16e/timesheet_grid/models/analytic.py", line 69, in read_grid
return super().read_grid(row_fields,
File "/mnt/custom_addons/odoo_16e/web_grid/models/models.py", line 59, in read_grid
return self._apply_grid_grouped_expand(domain, row_fields, results)
File "/mnt/custom_addons/odoo_16e/project_timesheet_forecast/models/analytic.py", line 19, in _apply_grid_grouped_expand
grids = super()._apply_grid_grouped_expand(grid_domain, row_fields, built_grids,
File "/mnt/custom_addons/odoo_16e/timesheet_grid/models/analytic.py", line 199, in _apply_grid_grouped_expand
timesheets = self.search(domain_search)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 1512, in search
res = self._search(domain, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4668, in _search
query = self._where_calc(domain)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4436, in _where_calc
return expression.expression(domain, self).query
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 447, in __init__
self.parse()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 721, in parse
right_ids = comodel.with_context(active_test=False)._search([(path[1], operator, right)], order='id')
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/project/models/project.py", line 1921, in _search
return super(Task, self)._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count, access_rights_uid=access_rights_uid)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4669, in _search
self._apply_ir_rules(query, 'read')
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4464, in _apply_ir_rules
expression.expression(domain, self.sudo(), self._table, query)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 447, in __init__
self.parse()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 674, in parse
raise ValueError("Invalid field %s.%s in leaf %s" % (model._name, path[0], str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field project.task.user_id in leaf ('user_id', '=', 51)

The above server error caused the following client error:
null
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwHcC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tVXy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZvFK.png)

I want to figure out, whether it is a access right issue, or it is issue about database.
And then solve it